# Notification setSound() doesn't seem to actually set a sound

Tags: android, uri, android-notifications

I recently started coding my first android project including notifications (SDK 21 - Android 5)

Currently, I have a tiny little button, that creates a notification on click and sends it to the app itself. Sound foolish but the purpose is to test if a custom sound and vibrate pattern is used.

This is the notification that gets constructed on click:

```
Notification note = new Notification.Builder(this.requireContext(), "channel_id")
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Text")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
        .setVibrate(new long[] {500, 500, 500, 500, 500})
        .setSound(SettingsHandler.getRingtoneUri(this.requireContext())
        .setContentIntent(anyIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build();
```

`SettingsHandler` is a helper class I created to handle settings. Like switching vibration on and off or picking a ringtone. `getRingtoneUri()` does the following:

```
public synchronized static Uri getRingtoneUri(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("table_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return Uri.parse(prefs.getString("ringtone_uri_key", RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION).toString()));
}
```

When debugging this the result of `getRingtoneUri` is something like `"content://media/internal/audio/media/31"`. This looks valid to me. However, in a later line, the sound property of the created notification is still null. Amy idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/ding");
       NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.getString(R.string.checkout_channel));
                mBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.passenger_name)).setContentText(context.getString(R.string.pit, name)).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon).setSound(alarmSound);
                Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                String channelDescription = "Checkout Channel";
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                            .build();

                    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(context.getString(R.string.checkout_channel),
                            channelDescription, notifManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                    notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                    notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
                    notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
                    notificationChannel.setSound(alarmSound, audioAttributes);
                    notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
                }
                notificationManager.notify(iUniqueId, notification);
```

You need to set the audioAttributes and create your notification channel. This works for me for all Android from 4.2 to 9

Comment: this would always set the same ringtone `Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/ding");` my intention was to set a ringtone, the user can chose, which is accessible with `SettingHandler.getRingtoneUri()`